# How to store files larger than 16mb in AWS DocumentDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am switching from MongoDB to AWS DocumentDB. However, in MongoDB, I used GridFs to store and retrieve files larger than 16MB. But this is not supported in AWS DocumentDb. Is there any way on how to store or process large files(>16MB) in AWS DocumentDB?
Any help or leads would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Usually you store large objects in S3, and your DB will just have references to them.

Comment: It can be convenient and more secure for data governance to have all your assets in the database but for large infrequently accessed assets S3 can definitely be cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

GridFS is a client construct and should just work with DocumentDB. However, we do not test it and thus don't officially support it. Did you encounter any issues when using GridFS with DocumentDB?

Comment: Hi,
We were able to work just fine using Gridfs with DocumentDB. No issues are observed till date :)

Answer (score -1):

If you switched to [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) which runs very nicely on to of AWS you would still be able to used GridFS to store your files.

Comment: We are working on MongoDB 3.2 version. We definitely need to upgrade it to atleast to 3.6. Can you suggest if it is feasible to upgrade it to MongoDB Atlas directly?

Comment: Yes you can use live migration to migrate your database. You will need to check for driver changes before you upgrade. The oldest version supported on Atlas is 3.6. What driver are you using?